# Copy entire row by checking condition and paste into different ranges of cells aside

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste

I am using below code to copy 4 columns of data from range A:D till the end of that row by checking a condition on B column whether its primary or backup. If primary category code will paste the data into columns K:N, if backup category paste the entire row to P:S columns.

But when executing I am getting Object Defined Error. Can anybody help with whats wrong in this code ? Thanks

```
Public Sub CopyData()


Dim rngSinglecell As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
Dim intCount As Integer

Range("K2:S1400").Clear

Set rngQuantityCells = Range("B120", Range("B120").End(xlDown))

For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells

  If rngSinglecell.Value = "Primary" Then

    Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell.Value,   14).Value = _
        Range(Range("A" & rngSinglecell.Row), Range("D" & rngSinglecell.Row)).Value
  ElseIf rngSinglecell.Value = "Backup" Then

    Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell.Value, 19).Value = _
        Range(Range("A" & rngSinglecell.Row), Range("D" & rngSinglecell.Row)).Value
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Fully [qualify the objects](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/macros-explained-part-2/)

Comment: Might if you select your worksheet and as @ScottHoltzman says fully qualify. Also can you provide some example data?

Comment: expample data, 5000049198 Backup 224.0E+6 95.0
500216H000 Primary 196.0E+6   92.0
500217H000 Primary 231.0E+6   91.0
500218H000 Primary 192.0E+6   95.0
5000052443 Backup 161.0E+6   97.0
5000052444 Backup 168.0E+6   97.0
500245H000 Primary 283.0E+6   91.3
500246H000 Primary 308.0E+6   83.9
500247H000 Primary 290.0E+6   93.0

Answer (score 0):

Try with Copy :

```
Public Sub CopyData()


Dim rngSinglecell As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
Dim intCount As Integer

Range("K2:S1400").Clear

Set rngQuantityCells = Range("B120", Range("B120").End(xlDown))

For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells

  If rngSinglecell.Value = "Primary" Then

    Range(Range("A" & rngSinglecell.Row), Range("D" & rngSinglecell.Row)).Copy Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

  ElseIf rngSinglecell.Value = "Backup" Then

        Range(Range("A" & rngSinglecell.Row), Range("D" & rngSinglecell.Row)).Copy Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

  End If
Next

End Sub
```

No need to resize.

Comment: Thank you so much, thats working well,   and is there anyway to modify this code to run the script whenenver there is a change is specific cell, Thanks

Comment: See [Worksheet_Change Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)

Comment: lest's say you want to call this subroutine when a change is made in A2, create the change event of the Sheet like this : Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
dim cel as range
Set Cel = Range("A2")
  If Not Application.Intersect(Cel, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
  ......
call CopyData
......
  End If
....
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Well, among other things, you're using `rngSingleCell.value` in two completely different ways, and one of them isn't working.

`rngSingleCell` is the cell that contains `Primary/Backup`, correct? But you're trying to use that value in a `resize` method, which expects a numeric value. This is definitely going to throw you off.

Of course, without seeing the actual layout of your data it's hard to be sure, but it's not clear why you're using a method a method like `Range().end(xlup).offset(1)` to define your copying range; it's going to keep on copying the same data that way.

Comment: Hi Werrf, Good catch on finding the logic that copying the same data again,    I didnot know a better way on getting only the updated values on to the resulting range with new data.     Yes, B column has either "Primary" or "Backup" and we need to check this and copy the rows based on this category.    Thanks